# Getting F on PageSpeed because not resized to 0x0

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed

I suddenly started getting an F for scaled images on PageSpeed Insights, and reading the details it said:

> ....jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 1024x680 to 0x0. Serving a scaled image could save 79.8KiB (100% reduction).

This is on a WordPress site.

I'm wondering if there is something in the theme or elsewhere that is somehow telling Google that those images are supposed to be 0x0, which isn't reasonable. Or perhaps the slider does that instead of hiding slides?

Thoughts on chasing this down so I can fix the 0x0 reference or not have it incorrectly picked up by PageSpeed Insights?

Comment: Sliders are bad user interface, don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to remove that reference since the images are in a slider.

It is generally accepted that sliders are bad for SEO. Yoast has written blog posts about it. They kill conversion rates, rankings, and surveys have shown that visitors are not impressed by them and their click rate is low (https://yoast.com/opinion-on-sliders/).

You can stop using the slider and instead create collages for your images where visitors can choose to browse. Your theme may support it, or a small amount of CSS can help you display images with neat effects -- if that is what you are going for. Here's some resources on that: https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Image+Filters+and+Effects

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to deviate from the community a little here and say that while sliders are rarely ideal, and frequently cause performance issues if not coded well, there are other factors - business goals, senior management directives, design concepts - that may unfortunately require that a slider remain present, at least until the trend dies out completely.

That said, when dealing with WordPress themes and plugins, the quality varies wildly. It can be hard to tell how a certain developer has coded the slider or what techniques they used to show or hide images.

Here, it does seem like there is some serious, slow resizing happening in the background. I would verify this by using DevTools to load the page and record what happens. Use the Network and Performance tabs, and see what's taking so long in the waterfall. You may be surprised where the source is coming from.

As for your slider issue - if that is indeed the issue, which it probably is - there are a few things you can do. You can try to fix the code yourself, or get a developer to do it. The resizing is probably happening with JavaScript, so start there: look for slider's JS files and see what can be done. There will be a lot of re-coding and debugging involved, so make sure you have a backup and do the work in a dev environment.

The easier option is to not use the slider you have; you can disable it if it came with the theme. There are lots of different slider plugins out there for WordPress, and some even take on the CSS properties of your theme. Do your research, and go with the lightest plugin (in terms of code and features) that is also highly rated by other developers.

Failing all of that, you can - as others have said - disable the slider, and then run the speed tests again and see what the impact was. If you're in the green again, you can consider alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of that, but the reality is that the client wants a slider, the slider is the best means to communicate their marketing, and so a slider is on the website.

I have never seen an image dimension of 0x0 generated from other sites with similar configurations and am tracking down the offending code, but meanwhile I am interested in the impact.